# Why does Excel Autofill formulas over whole table column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, autofill

When I put formula in first row of table column, formula is autofilled over whole column. But when I put it in any other row then first it works correctly. I would like to have differend formulas in that columns.

I have disabled Fill formulas in tables to create calculated columns.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pae97.png)

When debugging I found out that whole column is filled with formula after this block of code is executed. But I can not figure it out why. It drops cells which have formulas in them.

```
Public Function remove_numbers_formated_as_text(ByVal sh As Worksheet)

    Dim r As Range
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long '''' arr's rows
    Dim j As Long '''' arr's columns
    
    Dim s As String
    Dim B As Boolean
    
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    
    Set r = sh.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    arr = r.Formula2

    '''' Iterate over a whole row and then proceed to next column
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            If IsEmpty(arr(i, j)) = False Then
                
                '''' Check whether array member stores formula
                B = r(i, j).HasFormula
                If B = True Then GoTo A
                
                '''' If cell doesn't treat numbers as text and is a numeric value,
                '''' then this is definitely a measurement that somebody entered and
                '''' it is therefore converted from `Variant/String` to `Variant/Double`
                '''' by function `Val()`.
                s = r(i, j).NumberFormat
                If IsNumeric(arr(i, j)) And s <> "@" Then
                
                    '''' Check what decimal separator is useded.
                    '''' If is dot(.) then use function val() for convertion
                    If get_decimal_separator = "." Then
                        arr(i, j) = val(arr(i, j))
                        
                    '''' if it is comma (,) change decimal separator to dot
                    ElseIf get_decimal_separator = "," Then
                        arr(i, j) = Replace(arr(i, j), ",", ".")
                        
                        '''' convert it using val()
                        arr(i, j) = val(arr(i, j))
                        
                    End If
                    
                End If
            
            End If
A:
        Next
    Next

    r.Formula2 = arr
    
End Function
```